# How to sort a select element options with date value dd-mm-yyyy by month?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm using a select element to choose a date with this format dd-mm-yyyy.
I got the values from a rest api call and they're sorted by dd for a max of 7 options/days.
So, at the end of the current month, the first days on the next month comes up.

How can i sort the values in the right way maintaining a calendar structure ?

Thanks for any help?

```html
<select name="date" id="date" class="select">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
  <option value="01-02-2021">01-02-2021</option>
  <option value="02-02-2021">02-02-2021</option>
  ...
  <option value="29-01-2021">29-01-2021</option>
  <option value="30-01-2021">30-01-2021</option>
  <option value="31-01-2021">31-01-2021</option>
</select>
```

Comment: retrieve the `option` values, sort them, refresh the option within the `select` element

Comment: Simpler solution would be to sort your data before binding to option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write date ticks instead of date. Its easy way. But if you have to use that format, you can check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b61rmhLx/) link.

```
var opts = $("#date").find("option");
opts.sort(function(a,b){ 
    if(a.innerHTML.indexOf("-") == -1)
        return -1;
    return getDate(a.innerHTML).getTime() > getDate(b.innerHTML).getTime() ? 1 : -1;
});
opts.each(function(x){ 
    $("#date").append(this);
});

function getDate(strDate){
   var parts = strDate.split('-');
   return new Date(parseInt(parts[2]), parseInt(parts[1])-1, parseInt(parts[0]));
}
```